# 'Could I...?' for permission or request?

Tags: modal-verbs

I know we can use 'could I' for permission. Can we use it for request, too? Actually I'm saying this because I read this question:

> Could I have your address?

I think it's not asking for a permission. It's more of a request. Am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, for example

> [Could I have a coffee, please?](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22could+i+have+a+coffee+please%22)